# (Access & VB.NET) Query: Get MAX()

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, max

I need to display the last order number saved for each customer

Example:

**TABLE: CUSTOMERS**

```
ID_CUST | CUSTOMER
100 | JOHN
101 | MARY
```

**TABLE: ORDERS**

```
ID_ORDER  | NOTES | TOTAL | ID_CUST
1 | LOREM IPSUM | 100€ | 100
2 | PENDING  | 300€ | 100
3 | BLA BLA | 400€ | 101
```

If I execute this query:

```
Select CUSTOMERS.ID_CUST, CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER, MAX(ORDERS.ID_ORDER)
FROM CUSTOMERS INNER JOIN ORDERS ON CUSTOMERS.ID_CUST=ORDERS.ID_CUST
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.ID_CUST, CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER
```

works fine. Results:

```
100 | JOHN | 2
101 | MARY | 3
```

The problem is that I need to show "notes" and "total" fields too. Then if I run this:

```
Select CUSTOMERS.ID_CUST, CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER, MAX(ORDERS.ID_ORDER), ORDERS.TOTAL, ORDERS.NOTES
FROM CUSTOMERS INNER JOIN ORDERS ON CUSTOMERS.ID_CUST=ORDERS.ID_CUST
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.ID_CUST, CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER,ORDERS.TOTAL, ORDERS.NOTES
```

the results are not what I need [wrong]:

```
100 | JOHN | 1 | LOREM IPSUM | 100€
100 | JOHN | 2 | PENDING | 300€ | 100
101 | MARY | 3 | BLA BLA | 400€
```

because if I do not include these 2 fields, "notes" and "total", in the "Group By", the query returns error: does not include the specified expression as part of an aggregate function

**UPDATE 1:**

I am running this query from vb.net program

Comment: There is a wizard for this.

Comment: So what `Notes` do you want in the result?

Comment: PaulFrancis: Because my customer wants it that way

Comment: Fionnuala: with the wizard i am getting the 2nd query.....

Answer (score 0):

Save your first query (qryCustLastOrderID). Then create a new query (this is air code) SELECT qryCustLastOrderID.*, ORDERS.Notes FROM qryCustLastOrderID INNER JOIN ORDERS ON qryCustLastOrderID.MaxOfID_Order = ORDERS.ID_Order.

If you don't want to save a separate query, here is an alternative (again air code):
SELECT Q1.*, ORDERS.Notes FROM
(Select CUSTOMERS.ID_CUST, CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER, MAX(ORDERS.ID_ORDER) as MaxOfID_Order
FROM CUSTOMERS INNER JOIN ORDERS ON CUSTOMERS.ID_CUST=ORDERS.ID_CUST
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.ID_CUST, CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER) Q1 INNER JOIN ORDERS ON Q1.MaxOfID_Order = ORDERS.ID_Order

Comment: But I am launching this query from VB.NET application

Comment: it will still work, the second query will run the first.